# React Native Image component, requiring unknown module

Tags: react-native

The docs make it pretty clear that you can't do any dynamic requiring:

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

I have a use case that isn't so cut and dry however, I have a ListView and in the renderRow method i would like to render an Image depending on some of the data in said row.  For instance I want to render ../img/12.png, by doing it

```
<Image style={styles.thumb} source={require("../img/12.png")} />
```

works fine, however

```
let imagePath = "../img/" + row.number + ".png";  // row.number being 12
<Image style={styles.thumb} source={require(imagePath)} />
```

gives the following error:

```
Requiring unknown module "../img/12.png"
```

Is there any workaround here, it seems like its still ending up requiring the exact same string, it just doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out and figured I'd post an answer in case anyone in the future has this struggle.

The answer is that you need to explicitly require all images or else they will not be bundled, hence the unknown module error.

Solution:
In a separate file, I created and exported an object that is keyed by number, and the value is require("../img/x.png") where x is the key.
Then in my ListView's renderRow method I pull the image out from the object by keying into it using row.number

Answer (score 1):

you need to do :

```
let imagePath = require("../img/" + row.number + ".png")
<Image style={styles.thumb} source={imagePath} />
```